# Having two jQuery datepickers on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm using Timepicker (extended Datepicker from jQuery UI [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)).
My code:

```
$('.one').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "d"
});
$('.two').timepicker({
    timeFormat: "hh"
});
```

When I click on field .two, Firebug shows me an error:

> Error parsing the date string: Unexpected literal at position 2
>
> date string = 10
>
> date format = mm/dd/yy
>
> timepicker.js (line 1911)

Everything seems to work just fine, but I wonder why is this error showing up and how can I make it disappear?

EDIT:
Actually my code looks like this:

```
$('.one').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "d m y"
});
$('.two').timepicker({
    timeFormat: "hh mm"
});
```

EDIT2:
http://jsfiddle.net/r9bCk/

Comment: can you show us more code?

Comment: what is your expected date format? just 'd'? are you parsing this to date?

Comment: Try time format 'Hi' &instead of hh

Comment: I updated my post. That's my whole code. I don't do anything more.

Comment: I have a page with more than 5 timepickers (same jQuery UI plugin above), and they work perfectly. Try the code in http://jsfiddle.net to let us understand your problem.

Comment: The title suggests that the timepicker works if you remove the datepicker. Is this the case?

Comment: I updated my post with jsfiddle link. If you open Firebug or console you can see the error.
@Juhana If I remove the timepicker the datepicker works, no errors are shown.

Comment: I tried your demo link and it works after adjusting  time value  " 05 54 " to "05:54" , I guess issue being not able evaluate hours minutes correct ly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gury,
Try to include the addon v.1.1.0 from [here](https://raw.github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/v1.1.0/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js), and hopefully it resolves the error.
It's the same version I'm using.
Clearly there's a bug in the new versions.

Comment: Thank you. It works, however it would be awesome to use the newest and the most stable version..

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from the timepicker plugin itself. 
It is there in the example link. 
See $('#basic_example_2').timepicker(); after a selection.

[image]

Use a previous stable version as AsemRadhwi suggested